# Mistake in this number theory book

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm studying quadratic residues in this [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471625469), and I think this theorem is not stated correctly:

[image]
[image]

I think the author really means $(a,p)=1$, I don't know where he uses $(a,2p)=1$ in the proof.

Thanks in advance

Comment: $(a, 2p) = 1$ means $(a, p) = 1$ and $(a, 2) = 1$.

Comment: In the last paragraph you need $a$ to be odd, for the first statement of the theorem to hold.

Comment: Line -3 of the argument pretty explicitly makes use of the assumption, when indicating what happens when $a$ is odd (which follows from $(a,2p)=1$).

Comment: @AndresCaicedo yes, but the theorem 3.2 is the Gauss lemma which doesn't ask $a$ to be odd, just $(a,p)=1$

Comment: @vadim123 yes, but the theorem 3.2 is the Gauss lemma which doesn't ask $a$ to be odd, just $(a,p)=1$.

Comment: Please read and *understand* what is actually stated in line -3. Understanding is the important part, it goes beyond quoting a theorem.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/789201/help-in-this-theorem-in-number-theory

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I'm sorry, I understand now!

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė thank you for your remark

Answer (score 1):

Following the comments of the question:

Note $(a,2p)=1\implies (a,p)=(a,2)=1$. We need the first equality because the way $r_j$ and $s_j$ are defined in the proof of the Gauss lemma (theorem 3.2) the second one is required also because we need $a$ to be odd to have $(a-1)\frac{p^2-1}{8}\equiv0\pmod{p}$ and have $n\equiv \sum[\frac{ja}{p}]\pmod{2}$.